# Typesafe Application and Reference Config Files not Merging When Building Fat JAR

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, typesafe, typesafe-config

I have an sbt application that will run when ran through intellij or through the terminal using sbt run. However, when I create a fat jar to be able to deploy it to a server I get all kinds of `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution` errors. They aren't user defined ones in my application conf, they are all the ones that are defined in the multiple akka conf files.

I have tried merging them using the below:

```scala
val config = ConfigFactory.load(getClass().getClassLoader())
```

```scala
private lazy val userConfig = ConfigFactory.parseResources("application.conf")
val config = userConfig.resolve()
```

```scala
mergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x if x.contains("akka\\http\\") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x if x.contains("akka/http/") => MergeStrategy.concat
```

I ahve also tried to hardcode whatever value it complains about in my application.conf, but it just complains about another variable that it can't resolve.

Comment: Could you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if I built the fat jar using `sbt assembly` instead of the IntelliJ way then it worked.